# In Codeigniter Webcam Using upload image in folder and database

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, codeigniter

**View code**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onClick="take_snapshot()"><i class="fa fa-camera fa-fw"></i>Capture</button>
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 imager" id="results" name="results">       
    <input id="results" type="" name="results" value=""/>
    <div class="clearfix" id="my_camera"></div>
    <input type="file" name="webcam">

    function take_snapshot() {                
        Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML ='<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
        });
        Webcam.upload(data_uri, '"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Enquiry_Management/Demosave"', function(code, text) {
            if (code === '200') {
                alert ('ok');
            } else {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }

    Webcam.set({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        upload_name: 'webcam',
        jpeg_quality: 90
    });

    Webcam.attach('#my_camera')
```

**Controller code**

```
$filename = date('YmdHis').".jpg";
$filepath = FCPATH.'uploads/'.$filename;
$result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'],$filepath);
```

**Description**

I want to Image Click through Webcam and save in to the folder and database using Codeigniter MVC framework. This is my view and controller Code. Please help me to save and print image file name in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

You can use this to upload images to your server.

An example:

```
 $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';//your path to saving it
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))//the name of the input. In your case 'webcam' instead of 'userfile'
            {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            }
```

Hope this helps!